# Meu formulário nao envia para o banco

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

Criei um `form` para salvar dados no banco **MySql**, mas não está funcionando como esperado.

Estou com dificuldade para identificar o problema pois não aparece nenhum erro, a página apenas da um refresh.

**Tabela no Banco:**

```
id_contato (int11 aI)
, nome_contato
, email_contato
, assunto_contato
, categoria_contato
, msg_contato
```

**Formulário:**

```
    include "seguranca.php";


    if(isset($_POST['submit']) )
    {
       $nome_contato=$_POST['nome_contato'];
       $email_contato=$_POST['email_contato'];
       $assunto_contato=$_POST['assunto_contato'];
       $categoria_contato=$_POST['categoria_contato'];
       $msg_contato=$_POST['msg_contato'];



       $msg_query = "INSERT INTO  contato (`nome_contato`, `email_contato`,`assunto_contato`, `categoria_contato`, `msg_contato`) VALUES ('$nome_contato', '$email_contato', '$assunto_contato','$categoria_contato', '$msg_contato')";
      try
      {
         $register_result = mysqli_query($conn, $msg_query);
         if($register_result)
         {
            if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn)>0)
            {
              echo("Mensagem enviada com sucesso!");
            }else{
               echo("Erro no envio da mensagem.");
            }
         }
      }
      catch(Exception $ex)
     {
        echo("error".$ex->getMessage());
     }
   }
?>
  <html>
  <body>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <form method="POST" action="suporte.php" class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Nome" 
         name="nome_contato" placeholder="Nome">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="Email" 
            name="email_contato" placeholder="Email">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Assunto" 
              name="assunto_contato" placeholder="Assunto">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <select class="form-control" name="categoria_contato" 
               id="Contato">
                        <option value="none" selected disabled>Selecione uma 
             opção de contato</option>
                        <option value="Suporte">Suporte</option>
                        <option value="Bug">Relatar um bug</option>
                        <option value="Sugestões">Sugestões</option>                            
                        <option value="Elogios">Elogios</option>
                        <option value="Reclamações">Reclamações</option>
                        <option value="Contato">Contato com a Cats2</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <label id="Texto"> Mensagem: </label>
                    <textarea style="height: 134px; resize: none; width: 
                    330px;" class="form-control" rows="4" id="Texto" 
                   name="msg_contato">
                    </textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6"> 
                        <button class="btn-sm btn btn-default" type="submit" 
          name="submit" value="submit" > Enviar Mensagem</button>
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Apresenta algum tipo de erro?

Comment: Nenhum cara, por isso eu n to conseguindo resolver :(

Comment: Você está tentando usar exceções com MySQLi, mas configurou o MySQLi para isso? Normalmente com MySQLi se usam as funções de erro, que são muito mais práticas e sensatas que exceções.

Comment: tente usbistituri por 'aspas' simples

Comment: Não tem que colocar apóstrofo nesta parte INSERT INTO  contato (nome_contato, email_contato, 
    assunto_contato, categoria_contato, msg_contato)

Comment: coloque nos campos do formulário além do atributo name o id também

Comment: retire o apóstrofo e coloque aspas duplas . Seu tratamento de retorno do try/catch também está incorreto.

Comment: Coloquei as funçoes de erro do MySQLi, e adicionei o NULL para inserção do ID no meu msg_query. Agora está funcionando, agradeço a atç de todos.

Answer (score 1):

Porque não usa o pdo?

```
require_once('../conexao.php');

// Pegando os parametros
@$nome_contato = $_POST['nome_contato'];
@$email_contato = $_POST['email_contato'];

// @$nome_contato = ola;
// @$email_contato = "ola@ola.com";

$pdo = $dbconn->prepare("INSERT INTO contato (nome_contato, email_contato) VALUES (:nome_contato, :email_contato");
$pdo->bindParam(':nome', $nome);
$pdo->bindParam(':email_contato', $email_contato);
$pdo->execute();
```